# Can't figure out how to use Schema Directives when moving to Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, apollo-server, graphql-js

I spent few days rewriting my GraphQL server to Typescript, but in the end, got stuck with defining Schema Directives. Already spent a lot of time googling and found no examples of "more advanced" Apollo GraphQL with Typescript.

It works perfectly for me when using plain Javascript, had no issues with that and my Directive looks like this:

```js
// TS but no difference from JS in terms of extended class or method overriden
export default class UserAuthDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  visitFieldDefinition(field: any, details: any) {
    field._requiredRole = this.args.role
    const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field
    field.resolve = function (...args: any) {
      // LOGIC CHECKING ROLES
    }
  }
}
```

I use *makeExecutableSchema* from *graphql-tools* library which looks like this:

```js
// Again basically identical with original JS
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: mergeTypes(types, { all: true }),
  resolvers: loadResolvers(),
  logger: {
    log: (e) => logger.error(e.message, e),
  },
  allowUndefinedInResolve: false,
  inheritResolversFromInterfaces: true,
  resolverValidationOptions: {
    allowResolversNotInSchema: false,
    requireResolversForResolveType: true,
  },
  schemaDirectives: {
    userHas: UserAuthDirective,
    // ^^^ Here I'm getting. "Type 'typeof UserAuthDirective' is not assignable to type 'typeof SchemaDirectiveVisitor'. Types of property 'visitSchemaDirectives' are incompatible."
  },
})
```

The constructor of *SchemaDirectiveVisitor* is protected therefore I can't instantiate the class from there.
I am not really advanced Typescript user, so maybe I am just understanding it completely wrong or missing some basic concepts, but I got really stuck on this and will be glad for any tips or guesses what I could be doing wrong.

Thanks :-)

Comment: Are you importing `SchemaDirectiveVisitor` from `graphql-tools` or `apollo-server`?

Comment: Man, you saved me a lot of hair pulling :-D Thanks a lot! Of course I was using `apollo-server` one and not the `graphql-tools`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you're importing `SchemaDirectiveVisitor` from the right package -- `graphql-tools` and not `apollo-server`. Depending on the versions of each package, it's very likely that the `SchemaDirectiveVisitor` classes exported by each the packages are not compatible with one another.

Comment: Note also changes in API from `graphql-tools` to some versions of `@graphql-tools` packages
Especially: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/8481

Answer (score 1):

I see two arguments in your `visitFieldDefinition` method.

The implementation of this class varies with implementation of the graphql.

**If you are using apollo-server**:

When implementing `SchemaDirectiveVisitor` you need to override one of the visit method, and these methods take only one argument. Hence, the method is overloaded and not overridden.

Please refer to the page below :

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/creating-directives/

**If you are using graphql-tools**:

The method takes 2 arguments which look like `visitFieldDefinition(field: GraphQLField<any, any>, details: { objectType: GraphQLObjectType | GraphQLInterfaceType })`

Please refer to the page below :

https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/legacy-schema-directives/#implementing-schema-directives

Comment: That's really weird because SchemaDirectiveVisitor actually extends SchemaVisitor, where the visitFieldDefinition definition looks following:

```typescript
visitFieldDefinition(field: GraphQLField<any, any>, details: {
        objectType: GraphQLObjectType | GraphQLInterfaceType;
    }): GraphQLField<any, any> | void | null;
```

Comment: In that case, you need to figure out which exact implementation are you using. The function definition varies with the implementation like, the way `apollo-server` only uses one argument, and the `graphql-tools` uses 2 arguments

Comment: Yes, you're right thanks a lot @MegaMind . Daniel Rearden hit the nail on the head - I was using SchemaDirectiveVisitor from wrong package.